# Remove global implicit function - avoid ambiguous operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, rvalue

Let's say I have an enum class:

```
enum class PType : int
{
   Parallel     = 0,
   AntiParallel = 1,
   BiParallel   = 2,
   NotParallel  = 3
};
```

I now want to create the two operators

```
bool operator==(PType lhs, PType&& rhs)
bool operator==(PType&& lhs, PType rhs)
```

so that I can find out on which side of the == my rvalue reference is placed.

Unfortunately I get a compiler error

> error C2593: 'operator ==' is ambiguous

in VisualStudio because the compiler automatically generates the following operator:

```
bool operator==(const PType lhs, const PType rhs);
```

for it. Trying to delete it with

```
bool operator==(const PType lhs, const PType rhs) = delete;
```

doesn't result in an compilation error in that line but I still get the "is ambiguous" error afterward.

Any ideas on how to make this work?

**EDIT:**
I know how to do it with a regular class but I still want to figure out why the compiler produces the error. I know the code is sketchy, bad style and could lead to errors as mentioned by many. 
Anyway, I had the idea that this type of thing could work and so I tried and I think it can still work if I only could get "= delete" to work.
So now I ask this question out of pure academic interest because I want to learn more about the compiler and why the compiler reports no error when I delete the function but then complains a few lines later that the allegedly deleted function is considered an overload candidate.

The reason why I want to differentiate between where the rvalue reference is because then I know on which side of the == the variable is and on which side the compare value like PType::BiParallel can be found. The reason for this is that a variable containing Parallel or AntiParallel compared with PType::BiParallel should return true as I just want to know if we have some sort of parallelism. On the other hand if the variable contains BiParallel and is compared against PType::Parallel or PType::AntiParallel both comparisons should be false because you can not say which one is true. 
Again, I know this is bad style but I find it academically interesting why the compiler is accepting the "= delete".

Comment: Why do you need the rvalue reference arguments, I just don't see it making any sense? What is the actual and underlying problem you need to solve using rvalue references? What is the use-case? How will (and do) you use the comparison operator?

Comment: Why do want to "find out on which side of the `==` my rvalue reference is placed"?  This maybe an X/Y problem.

Comment: I have a variable which holds let's say AntiParallel. This should return true when compared with BiParallel. When the variable holds BiParallel it should only be true when compared with BiParallel. I think I will write a class for it to make my intentions clearer but I still want to know why I get a compiler error. Like this: var == PType::BiParallel

Comment: I don't see you needing rvalue references for that. Just check something like `return (lhs == AntiParallel && rhs == BiParallel || lhs == rhs);` And you can do that by taking *both* arguments by value.

Comment: Thats not enough. someone could write PType::BiParallel == var which should be true if var = AntiParallel.

Comment: `void Foo(Bar bar)` and `void Foo(Bar&& bar)` the overload is ambiguous, because either one is equally a valid option when the parameter is an rvalue.  `void Foo(Bar const& bar)` and `void Foo(Bar&& bar)` are not ambiguous.

Comment: Please explain why you don't just implement `bool operator==(PType, PType)` and nothing else? How is the value category of any relevance to `operator==`? I don't see a problem: https://godbolt.org/z/H5EAQ8

Comment: Please take some time to refresh [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Include all details in the question itself, like the underlying problem you're trying to solve, why you need to differentiate between e.g. the literal `PType::Parallel` and a variable with that value, and other requirements you have. Preferably with a rationale behind the requirement (unless it's for a school assignment or similar, when there often isn't a rationale).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had written another answer to this question, but the OP pointed out that my answer was incorrect. Upon thinking about this more, I believe that what the OP is trying to do is simply not possible.

As described in C++17 [over.built]/16, during overload resolution, a built-in candidate is generated with the signature

```
bool operator==(PType, PType);
```

If the built-in candidate is selected, then the built-in semantics of `==` will apply.

Now, it is possible to define your own `operator==`, but unless you declare one *with the same exact signature* as the built-in candidate, the built-in candidate will still get generated. Thus, at overload resolution time, the built-in candidate either wins (due to exact match), or is tied with some user-declared overload, resultin in ambiguity.

If you do declare your own `operator==` with the exact signature of the built-in candidate, then the built-in candidate is not generated ([over.match.oper]/(3.3.4)). You are allowed to delete it if you wish:

```
bool operator==(PType, PType) = delete;
```

However, a deleted function still participates in overload resolution (unless it is a defaulted move constructor or move assignment operator). Therefore, this does not solve the problem: with additional overloads such as

```
bool operator==(PType&&, PType);
```

there is potential for ambiguity, and such ambiguity only arises once the argument types are actually known. That's why the compilation error doesn't occur until you actually try to use `==`.

What you really want is some way to prevent the built-in candidate, or another function with the same signature, from being considered by overload resolution at all. If you could do so, then you could force an overload to be chosen based on value category from an overload set like the following:

```
bool operator==(const PType& lhs, const PType& rhs);
bool operator==(const PType& lhs, PType&& rhs);
bool operator==(PType&& lhs, const PType& rhs);
bool operator==(PType&& lhs, PType&& rhs);
```

But as far as I can see, there is no way to do this, so what the OP wants does not seem possible.